# How to get better at intermediate and difficult pencil-and-paper calculations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Out of pure curiosity I recently had a look at some old Cambridge mathematical tripos questions from the 19th century. Those guys certainly knew how to handle difficult algebraic (and even arithmetic) expressions! Of course mathematics education has moved on since then, and in general that's probably a good thing. But on the other hand, I believe we've lost something, too, by abandoning things like long division of all but the simplest polynomials (which they never bothered teaching me in high school anyway). So, my question is: **how to become better at complicated algebraic gymnastics?** The problem isn't that I don't know what to do; it's more that I'm slow and prone to making lots of small mistakes (especially with minus signs).

The obvious answer is practice, lots of it. Unfortunately I'm under the distinct impression that modern textbooks aren't really the best tools to improve one's algebraic "nimbleness". I've also tried some of the older textbooks (like Chrystal's *Algebra*), but these aren't really "it" either. Possibly because they originated in a pedagogical tradition so vastly different from the one I grew up in.

The concept-and-proof side of mathematics is pretty familar to me now, after long years of study. But on the purely computational side I still fall short dramatically sometimes. I'm pretty sure that I'm not alone in this.

Let me end this question with a not-too-difficult example problem from some long-past Cambridge tripos. (J. Wolstenholme's problem book, no. 120 in the 1878 edition.)

*Prove that*
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\{(a+b)(a+c)+2a(b+c)\}^2-(a-b)^2(a-c)^2}{a}\equiv\\
\frac{\{(b+c)(b+a)+2b(c+a)\}^2-(b-c)^2(b-a)^2}{b}\equiv\\
\frac{\{(c+a)(c+b)+2c(a+b)\}^2-(c-b)^2(c-a)^2}{c}\equiv\\
8(b+c)(a+c)(a+b).
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

The judicious use of auxiliary variables is frequently helpful.  For instance, let $u = (a+b)(a+c)$, $v = (a-b)(a-c)$, $w = a(b+c)$.  Then we also see that $$u-v = 2a(b+c) = 2w,$$ hence $$u+v = 2(u-w).$$ Therefore $$\frac{(u+2w)^2 - v^2}{a} = \frac{(u+2w-v)(u+2w+v)}{a} = \frac{4w(2u)}{a} = 8(b+c)(a+b)(a+c),$$ as claimed.  The other identities follow from symmetry.

Comment: Beautiful solution!